# New to Management Information testing

Tags: manual-testing, test-management

I am starting a new role as a Management Information tester. Can someone give me some beginners advice please. I keep hearing source and target? What exactly does this mean?

Comment: The source is where the data's coming from, and the target is where the data's going to

Comment: Thank you! Is there any other information that may be useful to me ? i am struggling to find anything online ? Is it just a case of checking the file type, file layout etc or is there more to it than that?

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to [Management Information](https://www.guru99.com/mis-definition.html) testing, you might also want to look at ETL ([Extract, Transform, Load](https://www.guru99.com/utlimate-guide-etl-datawarehouse-testing.html)) and [Data Warehouse](https://www.guru99.com/utlimate-guide-etl-datawarehouse-testing.html) testing - I think it'll be useful to you.

The actual testing you'll undertake will still depend on the requirements given, but the links above should point you in the right direction.

**MI definition:**

> MIS is the use of information technology, people, and business
>   processes to record, store and process data to produce information
>   that decision makers can use to make day to day decisions.

**Source to Target:**

> In layman's terms, S2T testing ensures that AAA (in your Source) is
>   correctly mapped to AAA (in your Target), so when information is extracted, transformed, and loaded, the data is correct. The same applies to BBB, CCC, DDD, and so on.

This article on "[Why Source to Target Mapping documents matter](http://www.christoolivier.com/why-source-to-target-mapping-documents-matter/)" might be useful to you, even though it's written from a developer's perspective.

Comment: What’s the difference between Source to target testing and functional testing ? Also what is SAS?

Comment: That's a really big question. Source to Target testing and Functional testing are two very different beasts... you're basically asking for the difference between apples and pears. SAS is the software and language for statistical analysis (like SQL, for example) - there's lots of information on SAS on the web if you need to find out more, but I'd recommend a course if you've not used it before.

Comment: Thanks! What is Source to Target testing then?

Comment: You'll need to test the mapping between the Source and the Target. Some of the answers to this question might help you; https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/30868/9208